# mysql query use distinct in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I want to write a query where `distinct` can be used in the `where` clause.

so far i have following

`select distinct hostname from table`
I want to write something like:

`select id from table where distinct hostname`

Comment: So for each hostname, you would like just one id, and not many ids?

Comment: Are you looking for `COUNT(hostname) = 1` ?

Comment: any example, so that we can understand your goal?

Comment: Wont group by hostname  fetch fields with distinct hostname values?

Comment: Please give more details : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Learn SQL syntax.

Comment: What is the end goal? What are we attempting to achieve? *Why* do we want to write something like "`where distinct hostname`". The specification is ambiguously unclear about what result is supposed to be returned. Example data and expected output would go a long ways towards illustrating the specification, where expressing a desire to write broken SQL fails to give any useful information about the actual requirement.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47820035/4104224) question I just answered? *(Hint: If so, the answer for yours is VERY similar.)*

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you want:

```
select min(id), hostname from table group by hostname
```

That will select each distinct hostname, along with one (smallest/first) of its ids.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the `DISTINCT` keyword in `WHERE` clause but you can select distinct id's of different hostname as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE hostname IN ('xyz', 'yza', 'abc')
```