# Find duplicate concat values

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I'm trying to find each row with duplicates in a MySQL database.

```
1   alex    smith
2   bob     smith
3   alex    smith
```

I want to return:

```
1   alex    smith
3   alex    smith
```

This code will find duplicates, but it doesn't list each row that is a duplicate.

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(`firstName`, ' ', `lastName`) as full_name,
    COUNT(*) d
FROM users
GROUP BY full_name
HAVING d > 1;
```

The code below is what I'm trying to get each row that is a dupliate, but I get the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'full_name' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"

```
SELECT CONCAT(`firstName`, ' ', `lastName`) as full_name
FROM users
WHERE full_name IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(`firstName`, ' ', `lastName`) as full_name
    FROM users
    GROUP BY full_name
    HAVING COUNT(full_name) > 1
)
```

Comment: why not a simple: `where firstName='x' and lastName='y'`?

Comment: @Ali OP wants to find all other duplicates as well.

Comment: ahhh okay, understood the question wrong

Comment: "*" makes no sense in the context of this query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in WHERE clauses; and you do not actually need the CONCAT *(it increases your computational costs in this case)*; instead you can compare "tuples".

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE (`firstName`, `lastName`) IN (
    SELECT `firstName`, `lastName`
    FROM users
    GROUP BY `firstName`, `lastName`
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```